# Pass array to linkTo helper

Tags: ember.js

I want to create a component which needs to generate dynamics links. I tried passing the link data as an array, but this does not work.

```
var user1 = get("store").find("user", 1);
var data = {link: ["users.show", user1], title: "User1"};

{{#link-to data.link}}{{data.title}}{{/link-to}}
```

This should be equal to

```
{{#link-to "users.show" 1}}{{data.title}}{{/link-to}}
```

How to generate fully dynamic links from a variable?

Comment: I think link-to won't work for that, you might need create a custom helper, or use a function in a controller that 'Transitions' to the given route. Take a look here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/vendor/route-recognizer.js you can use the 'recognizer' to recognize the given path, you'll get a handler, and then transition to that route.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify an array as `params` argument into a `link-to` helper. Similar to [nickiaconis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31123175/revisions) answer, but with just the default `{{link-to}}` helper:

```
{{#link-to params=data.link}}{{data.title}}{{/link-to}}
```

...will render something like:

```
<a href="/users/show/1">User1</a>
```

(tested with Ember 2.3.0)

Comment: This is the Ember 2.0 answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Ember 1.13.x

The [LinkComponent](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js), which is what the link-to helper creates for you, is exposed as [-link-to](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.0/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L1060). I've created an example of its use here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rinukefuqe/2/edit?html,js,output

```
{{#-link-to params=(unbound link) hasBlock="true"}}
  {{title}}
{{/-link-to}}
```

The `params` attribute is what the link-to helper normally bundles your positional parameters onto, although you must use the unbound helper here because the LinkComponent [expects params to be an array](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js#L373) rather than a value binding object. Additionally, [the determination of use as block or inline component is not built into components yet](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js#L408), so you must pass `hasBlock="true"` unless you include the link text as the first parameter in your array.

---

## Ember ≤ 1.12.x

Although it is not done already, you can manually expose the [LinkView](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.12.0/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js) component, which is the equivalent of the new LinkComponent.

```
App.XLinkToComponent = Ember.LinkView.extend();
```

Then use it like:

```
{{#x-link-to params=link}}
  {{title}}
{{/x-link-to}}
```

Using `unbound` and `hasBlock="true"` are not necessary as the internal logic of LinkView differs from LinkComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't possible to pass an array, but you can pass each argument directlly, like the following:

**route**

```
  var user1 = this.store.find('user', 1);
  var data = { data: { link: "users.show", model: user1, title: "User1" } };
  return data;
```

**template**

```
  {{#link-to data.link data.model.id}}{{data.title}}{{/link-to}}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but this is not generic enough. What if one link takes one parameter and another link in the same array 2, 3, ...?

Comment: I think that with the link-to helper isn't possible. Maybe extending the link-to and creating a new one that expect an array could work. Someting like this `{{#link-with-args data.link data.args}}{{data.title}}{{/link-to}}`.